# MAUI Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be ProcessorArchitecture neutral

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui, .net-8.0

we just upgraded our Blazor MAUI Hybrid from .NET 7 to .NET 8, we are compiling on Azure DevOps Pipelines with the following command

```
dotnet publish -f:net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -r:win-x64 -c:Release -o:$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --no-self-contained
```

This has been working great for .NET 7 but now with .NET 8 it suddenly gives us the error:

> C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.3.230724000\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Build.Msix.Packaging.targets(1036,5):
> error : Packaged .NET applications with an app host exe cannot be
> ProcessorArchitecture neutral. Please specify a RuntimeIdentifier or a
> Platform other than AnyCPU.

We tried both with "win10-x64" and "win-x64". Any guidance on how to fix this so it compiles? We also tried setting the RuntimeIdentifier in the .csproj but then getting same error. Thank you

Comment: Do you have any `<Platforms>` entry in your .csproj?

Comment: @PMF - no such <Platforms> entries in the csproj

Comment: Then try `<Platforms>x64</Platforms>`.

Comment: Added <Platforms>x64</Platforms> and it still gives the same error

Comment: I'm not sure (and I haven't tried this yet), but maybe somebody could see something suspicious if you added your whole .csproj to the question.

Comment: Think this is the same problem as https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/37118

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `Platform` node in the .pubxml file from `Any CPU` to `x64`. Then the publish worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dotnet publish -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win10-x64
```